# IP address mask using TextInput

Tags: regex, qt, validation, ip, qml

I am trying to create a `TextInput` for IP addresses, and I need to control the ranges (`0-255`).

I used the `regExp` validator, and also an `inputMask` of `"000.000.000.000;0"` but this canceled the validator.

How can I create an IP validator with an input mask?

```
TextInput
{
  id: myLineEdit
  anchors.fill: parent
  cursorVisible: true
  focus: true

  validator:RegExpValidator
  {
    regExp:/^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$/
  }

  inputMask:  "000.000.000.000;0"
}
```

Comment: I tried you code, and everything seems to work fine with QtQuick 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the input mask.

And you should define different components for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Right, I just used his/her regular expression without input mask ... it works fine =)